# Print just 1/few word(s) covering the whole page

Tags: windows, gratis, printing

I often have to print just one or a few words in very large fonts filling up the entire A4 page, like signs (EXIT) or banners and such.

I usually do this in MS Paint by writing the text in a HUGE font, aligning it to the center, and print.

Is there an easier way to do this? Perhaps a software that's built entirely for the purpose of writing just a few words in large fonts covering the entire page?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this is word, pretty easy;

Navigate to the the Page Layout tab

1. Click on the very small bottom right of the page setup group to open
   the page setup window
2. Select landscape
3. Click the layout tab
4. Select the page vertical alignment to center then click ok

Now navigate back to the Home tab

5. Select center text

Now your text will be center of the page so you can adjust the font size to fill the page with the few words you need.

I have an image as well.

[image]

I have no idea why Word does not have a single button to align text both horizontally and vertically but this should be a bit faster than using MS Paint, especially if you save the document and use it as a template for future use.

Comment: Generally you don't align vertically on a page because what if the text is longer than 1 page? That's why Word only shows the button for vertical alignment for a table cell. But it does have the vertical alignment feature, or you still can create a text at the center of the page easily with the watermark feature

Comment: I didn't think of the watermark path but that is a valid solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to print a big short phrase on the page then you can use the [watermark feature](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/add-a-watermark-f90f26a5-2101-4a75-bbfe-f27ef05002de). In tab *Design* select *Watermark* and choose one of the predefined ones or create your own

[image: watermark]

Remember to change the color and transparency if you want it to be black

[image: watermark options]

---

Another way is using Word's [vertical alignment feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/align-text-left-or-right-center-text-or-justify-text-on-a-page-70da744d-0f4d-472e-916d-1c42d94dc33f)

In *Layout* tab press the small arrow on the *Page Setup* group, then in the *Layout* tab select *Vertical alignment*

[image: word vertical align]

---

*Old answer for filling the page with longer smaller texts:*

Those are called [filler text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filler_text)

In MS Word and PowerPoint there are `rand()`, `lorem()` and `rand.old()` for this exact purpose. You can change their parameters to get how many texts you want. MS Office generally isn't free, but it's [online version](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx) is free and you can try it right away.

- [How To Create Random Text In Microsoft Word](https://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/07/how-to-create-random-text-in-microsoft-word/)
- [How to insert sample text into a document in Word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/212251/how-to-insert-sample-text-into-a-document-in-word)
- [Automatically Generate and Insert Filler Text in Word 2010](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff960706.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Lorem Ipsum in PowerPoint presentations](https://www.free-power-point-templates.com/articles/lorem-ipsum-in-powerpoint-presentations/)

Note that it won't give just 1 or a few words but sentences/paragraphs. But generally it's better to fill the page that way instead of repeating a word again and again

There are also filler text generator add-ons in Chrome store

- [Lorem Ipsum Generator (Default Text)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lorem-ipsum-generator-def/mcdcbjjoakogbcopinefncmkcamnfkdb?hl=en)
- [Lorem Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lorem-generator/leenggkcnndpklaplhoelaopimghhgah)

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear, I know exactly what words I need to print. They're like signs (like EXIT) or banners and such.

Comment: @laggingreflex see my edit